# Other ways to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\int_0^t(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1})\mathrm dx}{t}\mathrm dt $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I need to evaluate the following limit :$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\int_0^t(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1})\mathrm dx}{t}\mathrm dt $$

Indeed, by substituting $$\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}= 1+ x+x^2 + x^3....+x^n$$

it immediately follows that $$L = \zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

But I'm looking for other ways to solve it. One idea is to evaluate the actual integral directly, but I've failed to do so. It seems like the inner integral has no nice form.
Answers of all level are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean, "evaluate the actual integral directly"? Is that not what you did to show $L = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$?

Comment: @NickF Yes. Sorry for confusion. I meant that it seems like the integral $\int_0^t\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\mathrm dx$ has no closed expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral $\,\,I(n)=\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{dt}t\int_0^t\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}dx\,\,$ has a closed form for at least any $n>-2$.

Indeed, making the substitution $x=ts$
$$I(n)=\int_0^1dt\int_0^1\frac{1-(ts)^{n+1}}{1-ts}ds\overset{t=e^{-x};\,s=e^{-y}}{=}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-(x+y)(n+1)}}{1-e^{-(x+y)}}e^{-(x+y)}dxdy$$
Switching to the coordinates $\,x=\frac{t+s}2;\,y=\frac{t-s}2$
$$I(n)=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-(n+1)t}}{1-e^{-t}}e^{-t}dt\int_{-t}^tds\overset{e^{-t}=x}{=}-\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\ln x\,dx$$
$$=-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int_0^1\frac{x^s-x^{n+1+s}}{1-x}\,dx\,\bigg|_{s=0}$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\big(\psi(1+s)-\psi(2+n+s)\big)\,\bigg|_{s=0}$$
$$\boxed{\,\,I(n)=\psi^{(1)}(1)-\psi^{(1)}(2+n)\,\,}$$
Using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula we can also find that at $n\to\infty$
$$I(n)=\zeta(2)-\frac1{n+2}-\frac12\frac1{(n+2)^2}-\frac16\frac1{(n+2)^3}+O\left(\frac1{(n+2)^5}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't know what $\phi$ is so I thought there's no closed form.

Comment: $\psi (x)$ is digamma, and $\psi^{(1)}(x)$ is tri-gamma function - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function  and   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function  correspondingly

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll learn them soon.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{\int_0^t(\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1})\mathrm dx}{t}\mathrm dt $$

Taking the numerator;
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^t\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^t 1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n\,\mathrm 
 dx\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+\cdots+\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$$

Recall, $\,\ln(1-t)=-\left(t+\dfrac{t^2}{2}+\dfrac{t^3}{3}+\ldots+\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}+\ldots\right)$

> $$L=\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(1-t)}{t} \,\mathrm dt=\zeta(2)$$
>
> Note - $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} \,\mathrm dx =
>  \ln(1-x)\ln(x)+Li_2(1-x)|_0^1=-\zeta(2)$
>
> Note - $Li_2(z)=-\int_0^z \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx, Li_2(0)=0, Li_2(1)=\zeta(2)$

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function, the inner integral is simple
$$f_n(t)=\int_0^t\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\,dx$$ $$f_n(t)=\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}-\log (1-t)-\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1} \,
   _2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;t)$$
Divided by $t$, the first and second terms do not make any problem.

For the last one,
$$\int t^n\,\,_2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;t)\,dt=(n+1)\, t^{n+1}\, \Phi (t,2,n+1)$$ where $\Phi(.)$ is  the Hurwitz[Dash]Lerch transcendent function.
$$\int_0^1 t^n\,\,_2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;t)\,dt=(n+1)\, \zeta (2,n+1)=(n+1) \psi ^{(1)}(n+1)$$ where appears the Hurwitz zeta function and/or the first derivative of the digamma function.

As a total
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac {f_n(t)} t \,dt=\frac {\pi^2}6+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\psi^{(1)}(n+1)$$
Using first $n=(m-1)$, expanding for large values of $m$ and replacing $m$ by $(n+1)$
$$I_n=\frac {\pi^2}6-\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2 (n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{6
   (n+1)^3}+\frac{1}{30
   (n+1)^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^7}\right)$$ which is extremely accurate (absolute error of $8.19\times 10^{-8}$ for $n=5$) and also gives ways to generate very tight bounds

Comment: Thanks claude sir. Unfortunately I've seen $_2F_3$ and $\Phi$ for first time so it went above my head.